# Comment multiple line using SED

Tags: sed, scripting

Seeking help how can i comment multiple lines using SED, i like to comment ftp, telnet, shell, time, ntalk, daytime in inetd.conf file.  Thanks in advance

[image: inedd.conf file in AIX OS]

Comment: (1) This is rather trivial.  (2) Probably you didn't even attempt to solve your problem by yourself.  (3) You exhibit utter laziness by posting a __screenshot__ of the input in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command should work.

```
 sed -e '/^ftp/ s/^#*/#/ ' -e '/^telnet/ s/^#*/#/' -e '/^shell/ s/^#*/#/' \
   -e '/^time/ s/^#*/#/' -e '/^ntalk/ s/^#*/#/' -e '/^daytime/ s/^#*/#/' inetd.conf
```

or a bit shorter in one expression:

with "Basic Regular Expressions":

```
sed '/^\(ftp\|telnet\|shell\|time\|ntalk\|daytime\)/ s/^#*/#/' inetd.conf
```

with "extended regular expressions":

```
sed -r '/^(ftp|telnet|shell|time|ntalk|daytime)/ s/^#*/#/' inetd.conf
```

Comment: Hi, this really help and it works! Thanks for the quick post...

Comment: Note that neither `-r` nor `\|` are standard/portable. `-r` is GNU specific.